# Is it possible to open a file with Windows compressed-folders ability without it having a .zip extension?

Tags: windows, compression, zip

In Windows (10), is it possible to open a file without a .zip extension using Windows native compressed-folder ability?

I occasionally have apps I need to append a .zip extension onto in order to open them with Windows (browser extensions, mobile apps, etc).

Rather than having to add these .zip extensions manually, I'm wondering if there's a way to use Windows' native compressed-folder ability without a file having a .zip extension, like something along the lines of adding an entry to the "Open With" context menu.

I realize there are third party workarounds like WinRAR and 7zip, but this question is more for understanding the possibility of using/triggering a native Windows function/ability outside of its standard usage.

Comment: Windows unzipper is dumb software, don't think you can.

Comment: This is more so about getting Windows to do something it can already do, just outside the standard routine it does it. Might be more of a reverse-engineering question, I suppose.

Comment: What do you mean "get it to do" its dumb software that only does certain things, no configuration allowed.  Why do you  think Everyone uses third party compression utilities.